# Determine if a file is present in a multiple file php upload

Tags: php

I have a form with 3 independent upload inputs

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file"  accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel"  />
<input name="upload[]" type="file"  accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel"  />
<input name="upload[]" type="file"  accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel"  />
```

Thus, I have an 'upload' array with the potential for 3 files, 2 of which the user must select, the third is optional

I want to, on the submission to the server, determine if a file has been selected for file 1 and file 2 separately

I have used this code, but all it tells me is whether or not any file has been selected, not specifically for file 1 and file 2:

```
   for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
$strl = strlen($tmpFilePath) . $strl;

if($strl==???){
}
 //do something 
}
```

The idea with the ' . $strl' was I thought if the for code was looping through the array, it would capture each temporary name (x characters long), but whether I input 1, 2 or 3 files, it always returns the same: 14, or one link, like: /tmp/phpVniKUq

I assumed with the code above if 2 files were present $strl would be 28, 3 files present 42

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't try checking filename lengths. There's no guarantee that they will be 14 char long.

You should instead inspect `$_FILES` global for error codes (or check filesizes) and continue depending on successful uploads like this:

```php
<?php 

var_dump($_FILES['upload']);
$uploadedCount = 0;
foreach($_FILES['upload']['error'] as $err) {
    if ($err === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $uploadedCount += 1;
    }
}

var_dump($uploadedCount);

?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" />
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" />
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" />

    <button>upload</button>
</form>
```

This checks error codes for inputs and displays the count of files that are reported to be successful by PHP [0]

[image: screenshot]

- [0]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to [abdusco's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59999369/157957), it's worth understanding why your current code doesn't work.

```
$strl = strlen($tmpFilePath) . $strl;
```

The `.` operator concatenates two strings, so `'abc' . 'def'` gives `'abcdef'`. But here, you're getting a number from `strlen($tmpFilePath)`, so you'll end up with `14 . 14`, which is `'1414'`.

What wou wanted was either:

- Concatenate the names themselves (`$str = $tmpFilePath . $str`) and then measure the total length at the end (`strlen($str)`)
- Measure the length of each name and *add* them with the `+` operator (`$strl = strlen($tmpFilePath) + $strl`)

However, since you don't actually care about the length, all you really need to know is how many, which can be implemented by incrementing a counter, with `$counter++`.